# Silverlight: Highlighting selected Image on StackPanel

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a `StackPanel` of `Image` objects that are created and added dynamically. How can I add a highlight/glow for a selected image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a glow around an object by applying a `DropShadowEffect`, see the following article for details:

http://www.silverlightshow.net/tips/Using-Blur-and-DropShadow-effects-in-Silverlight-3.aspx

To make a glow, simply create a `DropShadowEffect` with a zero `Direction` and `ShadowDepth` as per this blog post:

http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Home/tabid/67/EntryID/170/Default.aspx

In order to support selection, you should be using a `ListBox` rather than a `StackPanel`. You can then style the selected item, see the following question:

[how to customize the listbox selected item style in silverlight 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832772/how-to-customize-the-listbox-selected-item-style-in-silverlight-4)

Comment: But how can I dynamically do it on the selected image from a stack panel. If another image get selected, I have to undo the DropShadowEffect on the previously selected image.

Comment: I am using a StackPanel with Horizontal orientation. Can I make the list box horizontal? Tried  d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment", but not working

Comment: Sure - you just set the ItemsControl.ItemsPanel to a StackPanel with your required orientation. See the example half way down this page: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/02/google-sky-on-windows-phone-7/

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a `ListBox` if you want out of the box selection handling and create the highlight effect as a visual state in the `ItemContainer` template.